# Alternate row color ListView xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, colors

I have bind on my ListView, an ObersvableCollection.

And i want to alternate my row color of my ListView.

I found lot of code, but didn't work for me... If you can share an example/sample !

Like this :

[image]

But i don't know how i can do that ?

I work with Visual Studio 2015 / Xamarin forms.

My project must be work with Android and IOS.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this with XF.  The simplest approach would be to include an Index property in your Item model (you would have to set it manually as you add it to your List/Collection) that determines the color.  You could then bind the RowColor property to your ItemTemplate.

```
public class MyItem {

  public int Index { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public Color RowColor { 
    get {
      if (Index % 2) == 0))
        return Color.Red;
      else
        return Color.Blue; 
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use a ValueConverter to determine the Color based on the Index row - this would free your model from having to determine it's own color, which would be a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Work but if i delete an item, i have, for example : red - red - red - blue - red - blue...

Comment: I know, it has definite flaws.  You could also try to build some sort of indexed collection,

Answer (score 7):

You can use a custom ListView for that. This works, if your Cell inherits from `ViewCell`.

```cs
public class AlternatingListView : ListView
{
    public AlternatingListView(ListViewCachingStrategy cachingStrategy) : base(cachingStrategy)
    { 
    }

    protected override void SetupContent(Cell content, int index)
    {
        base.SetupContent(content, index);

        var viewCell = content as ViewCell;
        viewCell.View.BackgroundColor = index % 2 == 0 ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;
    }     
}
```

Comment: When I use this, the selected cell no longer gets highlighted, any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with grouped ListView as it assumes the grouping title cells as normal row cells and colors them too.

Comment: You have to use XFGloss to set the color otherwise you will lose your haptic feedback or as @John has mentioned that will lose highlight.

Comment: If you add/remove an item to list view it will not work. It will lose its order and listView will show two rows with same color beside each other.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be adding it to the objects contained within the listview itself before passing the listview into the binding context.

So for example, when requesting lists from an API and deserializing them, you can then proceed to iterate and assign a background color property to each object within the list:

```
            var response = client.GetAsync(EndPointHelper.GetEndPoint("MaintenanceForEquipment") + "/" + equipmentid).Result;
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var contentmaintenances = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Maintenance>>(content);
            var count = 1;
            foreach (var maint in contentmaintenances)
            {
                maint.BackgroundColor = count % 2 == 0 ? "#A1DBE4" : "#155DB0";
                maint.TextColor = count % 2 == 0 ? "#529CFF" : "#e9ecf0";
                count++;
            }
```

From there, you can access it in the ItemTemplate within your list view after assigning the records accessed to the binding context:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding EquipmentName}"
                            TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding StartDateString}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding MaintenanceTypeName}"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

If you want to use fewer iterations within your Xamarin code, you can implicitly generate the background color via whatever API you're working with assuming you have access to that as well so it only needs to be assigned one time and accessed again on the client side after calling the API.

Hope this helps anyone looking through this old question for another possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom view cell. I've written a custom view cell in my project and used XFGloss(XFGloss is an add-on for Xamarin.Forms projects that adds new properties to the standard XF page and control classes) to make the listView's rows colorful. Your listView will not lose the haptic feedback with XFGloss. It works with grouped listViews too. The custom viewCell which I used is :

```
 public class MyViewCell : ViewCell
    {
        private Color BackgroundColor
        {
            get => CellGloss.GetBackgroundColor(this);
            set => CellGloss.SetBackgroundColor(this, value);
        }

        public Color EvenColor { get; set; }
        public Color UnevenColor { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (!(Parent is ListView listView))
                throw new Exception(
                    $"The Binding Context is not {typeof(ListView)}. This component works only with {typeof(ListView)}.");

            int index;
            if (listView.IsGroupingEnabled)
            {
                index = listView.TemplatedItems.GetGroupAndIndexOfItem(BindingContext).Item2;
            }
            else
            {
                index = listView.TemplatedItems.IndexOf(this);
            }

            if (index != -1)
                BackgroundColor = index % 2 == 0 ? EvenColor : UnevenColor;
        }
    }
```

and its usage in the xaml file is simple as below line :

```
<components:MyViewCell EvenColor="White" UnevenColor="#eeeeee">
```