# How can I make a list view have alternating background colors? NET MAUI

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I am trying to create a list view where the background color alternates for each entry in the list. Is there a way to do this in MAUI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840783/alternate-row-color-listview-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways.And the method often recommended is through a [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/datatemplate).

1.Create a `DataTemplateSelector` that holds two templates and selects them based on the index of the item:

```
public class AlternateColorDataTemplateSelector: DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate EvenTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate UnevenTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        // TODO: cast `Monkey` to your Item 
        return ((List<Monkey>)((ListView)container).ItemsSource).IndexOf(item as Monkey) % 2 == 0 ? EvenTemplate : UnevenTemplate;
    }
}
```

2.In XAML, we can define two templates, one with the alternate color and one with the normal color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp0606.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp0606"
             >

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="evenTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="unevenTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:AlternateColorDataTemplateSelector x:Key="alternateColorDataTemplateSelector"
                EvenTemplate="{StaticResource evenTemplate}"
                UnevenTemplate="{StaticResource unevenTemplate}" />
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
 
        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="30">

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource alternateColorDataTemplateSelector}">

            </ListView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had read about data template selectors but didn't think to use them for this problem

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I added a LineNumber property to my view model and used a value converter to set the color.

**The value converter:**

```
public class NumberToAlternatingColorValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Color EvenNumberColor { get; init; } = Colors.Green;

    public Color OddNumberColor { get; init; } = Colors.Red;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is not int intValue
            ? Colors.Transparent
            : (intValue % 2) == 0
                ? EvenNumberColor
                : OddNumberColor;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("NumberToAlternatingColorValueConverter.ConvertBack");
    }
}
```

**Register the value converter**

I registered the value converter in my main resource dictionary like so:

```
<converter:NumberToAlternatingColourValueConverter
    x:Key="MagentaCyanRowColorConverter"
    EvenNumberColour="Magenta"
    OddNumberColour="Cyan" />
```

You can register more than one value converter with a different key for different colour combinations.

**Use the value converter**

And I used the bound value converter in my XAML like so:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Summary.Lines}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:SummaryLineViewModel">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding LineNumber, Converter={StaticResource MagentaCyanRowColorConverter}}">
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72512689/31569) we can used **DataTemplateSelector** to resolve your problem.

Alternative solutions,

1. You can use a **property in the model** and straight a way bind it to the row background. (In your case Grid's Background color)
2. You can use **triggers** make the color change by considering a logic.
   ( [Xamarin Forms Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers) )